# Perl to Oracle Connection Error: ERROR OCINlsEnvironmentVariableGet(OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID)

Tags: oracle, perl, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a remote oracle database in my perl app. 
When running the app, the following error appears:

```
"Connection Error: ERROR OCINlsEnvironmentVariableGet(OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID)"
```

I got Oracle Instant Client and placed it locally then set the Oracle Home env to it, as I don't have Oracle client installed there.
My code is below:

```
BEGIN {
       $ENV{NLS_LANG}           = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8";
       $ENV{OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID} = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8";
        $ENV{ORACLE_HOME} = #The path to the instant Oracle client";
        }
    #Connect to database
    my $DBHandle = DBI->connect(
        "dbi:Oraclehost=$host;sid=$sid;port=$port",
        $userName,
        $passWord
    ) or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

I'm using ActiveStat perl on Windows Server 2008, ORACLE 10g

Answer (score 1):

I could find the root cause. I used Oracle Instant Client lite (instantclient-basiclite-win64-10.2.0.5) which contains only binaries. Then I tried Oracle Instant Client - SDK, which contains only lib.

I found that I need to merge both to get my code working, I used the SDK as main client, created a bin directory into it then placed the lite client into it...it works !